# Can we say that $T^n$ is a positive operator?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal L (\mathcal H)$ be a positive operator. Can we say that $T^n$ is also a positive operator?

I am able to prove that if $n$ is even then $T^{n}$ is a positive operator since positive operators on a complex Hilbert space are self-adjoint. What can I say about $T^n$ if $n$ is odd?

Comment: If you define positive operators via the spectrum, then this is an immediate consequence of the spectral mapping theorem.

Comment: I don't know spectral mapping theorem @MaoWao. I only know that positive operators $T$ are those which satisfy $\left \langle Tx,x \right \rangle \geq 0.$

Comment: $T$ is positive definite iff $T=A^2$ for some non-singular self-adjoint operator $A$. Then $$
\left\langle {T^n u,u} \right\rangle  = \left\langle {A^{2n} u,u} \right\rangle  = \left\langle {A^{2n - 1} u,Au} \right\rangle  =  \cdots  = \left\langle {A^n u,A^n u} \right\rangle  > 0,
$$ for $u\neq 0$.

Comment: You should mention the definition of a positive operator. There's various equivalent characterizations, and the answer will depend on which one you know.

Comment: I have mentioned the definition I am using, in my comment above @MaoWao.

Comment: @Gary I am trying to prove that every positive self adjoint operator admits unique square root using the exercise I have asked as question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $T$ is self-adjoint, we have
$$
\langle T^{2n+1}\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle T(T^n\xi),T^n\xi\rangle,
$$
and since $T$ is positive, this expression is positive.